# Linq to XML Search

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

Just a quick check really.

I have an XML file that I will be searching using Linq to XML. My only issue is, the XML that my users will be supplying can either use Long Code tags, or Short Code tags, e.g.

`<FromPerson>Joe Bloggs</FromPerson>` - Long Code

OR

`<m175>Joe Bloggs</m175>` - Short Code

Here is a snippet of my code to show how I currently search the document (currently only searching using long codes):

```
prod.ProductID = product.Elements("ProductIdentifier").First(t => (t.Element("ProductIDType").Value == "45" || t.Element("ProductIDType").Value == "21")).Element("IDValue").Value;
```

So, the element 'ProductIdentifier' can either be that, or 'b221'.

Is just simply a case of putting an IF statement to evaluate if the XML tag is either long or short code, then get the value OR is there any quicker, more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: has to write if condition only in my view there is no alternate for it

Comment: @Deepesh Yeah I was thinking the same. I just wanted to check that there wasn't a better way to do it.

Comment: Are all your Tags short when one is short, or can they be mixed in the same xml ? If they can't be mixed, what about a Dictionary of shortTags and a Dictionary of longTags (shortTag is the key). You check if longTags or shortTags are used in the xml, selected the good Dic, and code can be like `product.Elements(selectedDictionary["b221"])`

Comment: It's hard to make a refactoring suggestion based on such a short example. If you have a lot of elements, and they are all structured in a similar way, element information could be extracted and logic reused. For example, it is not clear if `ProductIDType` or `IDValue` can also have short aliases. And, it depends on how complex these additional filters can get (e.g. "`ProductID` is assigned by finding an element `ProductIdentifier` or `b221`, which contains an element `ProductIDType` with value `45` or `21`, and then applying `IDValue`"). What about other elements? Is there always an `IDValue`?

Comment: So, if all assignments can be described in a similar manner, then yes, you can refactor this code to define the structure separately and then pass it through a parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about the order you can just query for both and join the results like this:

```
var results = document.Descendants("ProductIdentifier")
                      .Union(document.Descendants("b221"));
```

**EDIT**

If you do care about the order of elements you can use the query below:

```
var results = document.Descendants()
                      .Where(e => e.Name == "ProductIdentifier" || e.Name == "b221");
```